# How to include 2 columns under one column header using Jquery

Tags: javascript, html

This is my table html I am trying  to How to include 2 columns under one column header using Jquery I tried this code:

```
$('#test th.column_Column1').append( $('<th/>', {text : 'HEADER BOth'}) );
```

But it doesn't give the desired output:

[image]

```
<table class="xrounded_shadowed default footable-loaded footable" id="test">
<thead>
<tr>
<th class="select_checkbox footable-visible footable-first-column" style="width: 40px;"><label><input type="checkbox" onclick="toggleAll(this)" style="float:left;"><i></i></label></th>
<th class="column_Column1 footable-visible">Column1</th>
<th class="column_Column2 footable-visible footable-last-column">Hari</th></tr></thead>
<tbody>
<tr class="odd">
<td class="select_checkbox footable-visible footable-first-column"><label><input type="checkbox" name="d-49700-checkbox_username" value=""><i></i></label></td>
<td class="column_Column1 footable-visible" style=""><span class="footable-toggle"></span>01/01/2019</td>
<td class="column_Column2 footable-visible footable-last-column" style="">Tuesday</td></tr>
<tr class="even">
<td class="select_checkbox footable-visible footable-first-column"><label><input type="checkbox" name="d-49700-checkbox_username" value=""><i></i></label></td>
<td class="column_Column1 footable-visible" style=""><span class="footable-toggle"></span>01/01/2019</td>
<td class="column_Column2 footable-visible footable-last-column" style="">Tuesday</td></tr>
<tr class="odd">
<td class="select_checkbox footable-visible footable-first-column"><label><input type="checkbox" name="d-49700-checkbox_username" value=""><i></i></label></td>
<td class="column_Column1 footable-visible" style=""><span class="footable-toggle"></span>01/01/2019</td>
<td class="column_Column2 footable-visible footable-last-column" style="">Tuesday</td></tr>
<tr class="even">
<td class="select_checkbox footable-visible footable-first-column"><label><input type="checkbox" name="d-49700-checkbox_username" value=""><i></i></label></td>
<td class="column_Column1 footable-visible" style=""><span class="footable-toggle"></span>01/01/2019</td>
<td class="column_Column2 footable-visible footable-last-column" style="">Tuesday</td></tr>
<tr class="odd">
<td class="select_checkbox footable-visible footable-first-column"><label><input type="checkbox" name="d-49700-checkbox_username" value=""><i></i></label></td>
<td class="column_Column1 footable-visible" style=""><span class="footable-toggle"></span>01/01/2019</td>
<td class="column_Column2 footable-visible footable-last-column" style="">Tuesday</td></tr></tbody></table>
```

Comment: Sorry, I think you want to add 2 rows, not 2 columns, right?

Answer (score 1):

Add two rows instead and the first one should have one single column that spans across all columns

```
<table>
    <thead>
          <tr>
              <th colSpan="2">Column Header</th>
          </tr>
          <tr>
              <th>Column 1</th>
              <th>Column 2</th>
          </tr>
    </thead>
</table>
```

Here's a snippet with more details using jQuery to do it dynamically...

```js
$(function(){
  var $thead = $("<thead></thead>");
  $thead.append("<tr><th colspan='2'>Column Header</th></tr>");
  $thead.append("<tr><th>Column1</th><th>Column2</th></tr>");
  
  $("table").append($thead);
});
```

```css
table{
 width: 100%;
 border-collapse: collapse;
 border: 1px solid #333;
 }
 
 thead{
 background-color: #FFEB3B;
 }
 th, td{
 border: 1px solid #333;
 padding:4px;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

The `colSpan` and `rowSpan` attribute is used to do such kind of things.In this case use need to use `colSpan` to ur `<th>`. And then set its `text-align:center` and you will be done

```css
th:nth-child(1) {
    text-align: center;
}
th,td{
    border:2px solid
}
table{
border-collapse:collapse;
}
```

```html
<table>
    <thead>
          <tr>
              <th colSpan="2">Column Header</th>
          </tr>
          <tr>
              <th>Column 1</th>
              <th>Column 2</th>
          </tr>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td>Column 1 Item</td>
              <td>Column 2 Item</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Column 1 Item</td>
              <td>Column 2 Item</td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
    </thead>
</table>
```